# Is it possible to generate a one time link with discord oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, discord.py

#### Intro:

What I'm after is when a user signs up for my discord.py bot:

- they get emailed a one time use oauth2 link that will ask them to login into discord
- after logging in, I want it to automatically add them/invite them to the guild if they are not already added
- upon automatically joining the guild, automatically give them a specific role for signing up

---

#### Key points:

- I have a HTTP POST webhook that gets fired when a user signs up from the SAAS I'm using to handle user signs up
- The bot is currently only in my discord server, so scaling this bot for multiple servers is not a concern

---

#### What I've tried:

This is some rough draft code using FastAPI. This code is not tested and does not work.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64
import time

app = FastAPI()

key = Fernet.generate_key()
fernet = Fernet(key)

# this would get fired from my HTTP POST webhook once the user sucessfully signs up 
@app.post("/generate_link/{user_id}")
def generate_link(user_id: int):
    encrypted_id = fernet.encrypt(str(user_id).encode())
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    data = f"{encrypted_id.decode()}:{timestamp}"
    token = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data.encode()).decode()

    # send one time use encrypted url to user via email API 
    email_api.send("mydomain/validate_link?token={token}")

# this would get fired when user goes to onetime generated link 
@app.get("/validate_link")
def validate_link(token: str):
    try:
        # Decode the token from the query parameter and split the encrypted ID and timestamp
        data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token.encode()).decode()
        encrypted_id, timestamp = data.split(":")
        timestamp = int(timestamp)

        # Check that the timestamp is within the valid range (for example 10 minutes)
        if time.time() - timestamp > 600:
            return "Link expired"

        # Decrypt the user ID and do something with it
        user_id = int(fernet.decrypt(encrypted_id.encode()).decode())
        # redirect user to oauth2 link with discord now that we have verified them? 
        return f"User ID: {user_id}"
    except:
        return "Invalid link"
```

#### My ultimate question:

- Is there built in functionality to do what I want here with discord oauth2 and I can just send the user a link upon email sign up?
- Or do I need something custom like my attempt here with FastAPI? For example, splitting the steps apart and having one step generate the one time url and the second step signing in with oauth2/adding to guild/adding role

Thanks for anyone who takes the time to read through my post!

Comment: Hi. I posted an answer but deleted it realising it wasn't exactly what what asked. Why d you need a only one time use link since they are going to authenitifacte themselves throught Oath2 anyways?

Comment: hey you can repost your answer I'm still working on tying everything together but your answer helped me get to the final solution I was going for.

Ultimately, the one time link fiasco stuff I was doing was not necesary. I can achieve a one time use token by using the ```state``` param in the discord oauth2 parameters. So basically when HTTP post is fired from webhook, I generate a onetime state value and then after a user uses the oauth2 link that one time state won't work anymore so they can't reuse the link or share it

Comment: Sure. Do you wish for me to implement the ```state``` parameter in my code?

Comment: No worries , I'm going to add an answer to my own question with more details on how I tied everything together. Your answer was immensely helpful in that process, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Thanks to Oath2 you can do many things, such as add someone to a guild and give them roles in such guild, all in one go. I use Flask to do it since I'm most confortable with that, but it doesn't really matter.

First, you need a [discord Application](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Once you have it you go to OAuth2, URL generator and select at least `identify` and `guild.join`. Copy that URL and paste it in the variable in the code. The redirect uri should be the url to /callback of your Flask App.

Complete the rest of the variables at the beggining of your code (if you don't know how to get the IDs of the roles and server check out Discord Development mode).

Make sure the bot is on your server and that it has at least the `CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE` and `MANAGE_ROLES` permissions on it.

That is everything, the code bellow should work. What it does is use OAth2 to get the users id, and then uses it make it join the guild with the specified roles. You can now email the `AUTORISATION_URL`, or if you prefer your own url the URL to your Flask App.

I am aware that Flask may not be suitable for "production deployment" so consider adding `waitress` to the code.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import requests


API_ENDPOINT = 'https://discord.com/api/v10'
TOKEN_URL = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token"


OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = "" #Your client ID
OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = "" #Your client secret
OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:5000/callback" #Your redirect URL
BOT_TOKEN = "" #"Your application token here"
REDIRECT_URL = "https://discord.com/" #Where you wish to redirect your user.
GUILD_ID = 0 #The ID of the guild you want them to join
ROLE_IDS = [0] #List of the IDs of the roles you want them to get
AUTORISATION_URL = "" #The obtained URL


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return redirect(AUTORISATION_URL)



@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    print("flag")
    if request.values.get('error'):
        return request.values['error']

    args = request.args
    code = args.get('code')

    data = {
        'client_id': OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    r = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v10/oauth2/token", data=data, headers=headers)
    r.raise_for_status()

    #Get the acces token
    access_token = r.json()["access_token"]

    #Get info of the user, to get the id
    url = f"{API_ENDPOINT}/users/@me"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    #This will contain the information
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    print(response.json())

    #Extract the id
    user_id = response.json()["id"]

    #URL for adding a user to a guild
    url = f"{API_ENDPOINT}/guilds/{GUILD_ID}/members/{user_id}"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bot {BOT_TOKEN}"
    }

    #These lines specifies the data given. Acces_token is mandatory, roles is an array of role ids the user will start with.
    data = {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "roles": ROLE_IDS
    }

    #Put the request
    response = requests.put(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)

    print(response.text)
    return redirect(REDIRECT_URL)


app.run(port=5000)
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I added my full solution answer below

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds this from google:

Thanks to Clement's answer I was able to reach my final solution. After doing some more digging, I ultimately determined that I could make an oauth2 link a onetime use link by adding the `state` parameter. The `state` parameter can be passed with the oauth2 link. After the user authorizes with discord login, oauth2 redirects them back to your server (in my case Flask). Then after they have redirected we can check if this state token passed within the url has been used or not yet using a database (or something simple like on disk db for small use cases). I wanted to send users a onetime link so they would not be able to reuse the link or share it with their friends.

### Generating one time state token:

I did this using a hash. This code is dummy template code because I don't want to disclose exactly how I'm doing the hash but you can fill in the details with what you'd like to hash with. I then store this in a database to reference later when the user hits the aouth2 callback endpoint.

```
import hashlib 
import base64 

uniquestr = user_info_data_here + SALT
hash_obj = hashlib.md5(uniquestr.encode())
hash_digest = hash_obj.digest()
token = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash_digest).decode()

db.set(token, [user_info_id])
```

### Emailing users onetime oauth2 link:

I used smptlib to send them an email when the HTTP POST webhook is fired. I used an email html template to make the email look nice. This is also dummy code but you can put your own info in here if you want to use my code

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

   with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("mail.domain.com", 465) as server:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = 'Welcome'
        msg['From'] = "support@domain.com"
        msg['To'] = user_email
        msg.preamble = 'Welcome'
        server.ehlo()
        server.login("support@domain.com", EMAIL_PASS)
        msg.attach(MIMEText(html_text, 'html', 'utf-8'))
        server.sendmail("support@domain.com", user_email, msg.as_string())
```

### Oauth Callback endpoint:

After the user uses the link and authorizes with discord, discord will redirect to your oauth2 callback endpoint. Within this endpoint we can add the user to the desired guild and give them desired roles and then redirect them to a pretty "You're all done" success page. One key note is to add them to the guild (if they're not inside of the guild server yet), you'll need to send a put request. Then to give them roles, you'll need to send a patch request.

#### Config.py:

```
GUILD_ID = 123456
BOTH_ROLES = [123445, 1234456]
BOT_TOKEN = "yourtokenhere"
API_ENDPOINT = "https://discord.com/api/v10"
TOKEN_URL = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token"
CLIENT_ID = "123456"
CLIENT_SECRET = "yoursecrethere"
REDIRECT_URL = "yourdomain.com/oauthcallback"
SUCCESS_URL = "yourdomain.com/thank-you/"
OAUTH_URL = "yourgenerateddiscordoauthurl" + "&state="
```

#### Callback endpoint:

```
@app.route('/oauthcallback')
def callback():
    if "code" not in request.args or "state" not in request.args: 
        return "Error", 404 
    if request.values.get('error'):
        return request.values['error']
    
    code = request.args["code"]
    state = request.args["state"]
    
    # make sure token exists and hasn't already been used
    if state not in db():
        return "Error", 404 
    
    # Get oauth access token
    data = {
        'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': config.CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': config.REDIRECT_URL
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    r = requests.post(config.TOKEN_URL, data=data, headers=headers)
    r.raise_for_status()
    access_token = r.json()["access_token"]

    # get user info with access token
    url = f"{config.API_ENDPOINT}/users/@me"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    user_id = response.json()["id"]

    # Add user to guild and add roles 
    url = f"{config.API_ENDPOINT}/guilds/{config.GUILD_ID}/members/{user_id}"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bot {config.BOT_TOKEN}"
    }
    data = {
        "access_token": access_token
    }
    response = requests.put(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "roles": config.BOTH_ROLES 
    }
    response = requests.patch(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    db.delete(state)

    return redirect(config.SUCCESS_URL)
```